# Python vs. R in org-mode babel output graphics

Tags: python, org-mode, export-to-pdf, org-babel

I am trying to write up a report in org-mode.
Read data from a csv file (single column three rows, floating numbers), compare in a bar chart, have the chart embedded in the report so that it can be exported to latex and then to pdf.

I am having difficulty understanding as in what I am doing in bar creation part of the python code because R_plot works fine, meaning chart is embedded into the report under the same org-mode :export :results :file setting.

What am I doing wrong with the python code? If I run the python code on interactive mode, it produces the chart with no trouble but for some reason py_comparison.png isn't saved when I run by cell-block.

```
#+NAME: R_plot
#+BEGIN_SRC R :exports both :results output graphics :file r_comparison.png
# graph in R
library("ggplot2")
performance <- read.csv("comparison.csv", header=FALSE)$V1
df <- data.frame(resource = c("1node1core", "1node8core", "2node8core"), performance = performance)
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=resource, y=performance)) +
     geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue") + 
     theme_minimal() +
     ggtitle("Computation time (min) vs. Resource (type)")
p
#+END_SRC

#+NAME: python_plot
#+BEGIN_SRC python :exports both :results output graphics :file py_comparison.png
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

objects = ['1node1core', '1node8core', '2node8core']
y_pos = list(range(0, len(objects)))

performance = []
with open('comparison.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
    f_row = float(row[0])
    performance.append(f_row)

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.title('Resource vs. Time')

plt.show()
#+END_SRC
```

## +END_SRC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your header value for python code block is wrong. There is a difference between `:results <file name> file` and `:file <file name>`. According to the documentation (redacted for clarity):

[`:results file`](https://orgmode.org/org.html#results)

> There are four classes of :results header arguments. Each ‘src’ code
>   block can take only one option per class. [...]
>
> **Collection** [...]
>
> - value Default. Functional mode. Result is the value returned by the last statement in the ‘src’ code block. Languages like Python may
>     require an explicit return statement in the ‘src’ code block. Usage
>     example: :results value.
>
> **Type** [...]
>
> - file Interpret as path to a file. Inserts a link to the file. Usage example: :results value file.

[`:file <file name>`](https://orgmode.org/org.html#file)

> An external :file that saves the results of execution of the code
>   block. [...] Some languages, such as ‘R’, ‘dot’, ‘ditaa’, and ‘gnuplot’,
>   automatically wrap the source code in additional boilerplate code.
>   Such code wrapping helps recreate the output, especially graphics
>   output, by executing just the :file contents.

In python the result of `plt.show()` (or `savefig` for that matter) is `None`, the image is only a side effect, so nothing gets inserted. In R it works because of the boilerplate wrapper mentioned above

So in python you need to save and return your image instead of showing it. Something like this should work:

```
#+NAME: python_plot
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results img.png file

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.savefig('img.png')
return 'img.png'

#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

to save the plot (if you want to save it in some other directory, you can do so) and show it in the results as well ...

```
#+begin_src python :results output file :file img.png :output-dir img/ :exports both
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.savefig(sys.stdout.buffer

#+end_src
```

[image]